# kafka consumer request.timeout.ms retry exhaustion?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Hi According to https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#consumerconfigs_request.timeout.ms

> The configuration controls the maximum amount of time the client will wait for the response of a request. If the response is not received before the timeout elapses the client will resend the request if necessary or fail the request if retries are exhausted.

What is  `if retries are exhausted` ? What is the retry parameter in the consumer if any ? Because indeed we do have `retry.backoff.ms` as well ? So when does it stop ?

Comment: I also have the same question about what parameter defines the max retry number

Comment: it's `retries` and it defines how many times the client will retry before failing. `retry.backoff.ms` is the time _between_ each retry, and `request.timeout.ms` is per _individual_ retry. does it make sense?

Comment: @Eugene i think i did not ask the question well at the time. But essentially on the consumer side there is no way to define the maximum number of retry as on the production side. I think that is where my confusion was coming from. Essentially a consumer just keep trying in  indefinitely.

Comment: ah! right, afaik, you are correct indeed.